# bloquear ID da URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como faço para bloquear o ID do parametro da URL de um sistema que possuo, por exemplo, ao clicar em um registro ele mostra como url/Alterar/12 onde 12 seria o id por exemplo, porem se o usuário trocar o 12 pelo 13 ele consegue editar o registro 13, como faço para bloquear pra ele editar somente o registro que ele clicou, no caso o 12, como bloquear para nao ser trocado pela url?

Código da Action na Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Analisar")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Editar(long id)
{


    var model = new AssociacaoCooperativaViewModel() { Id = id };

    if (model.Id > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var associacao = await AssociacaoCooperativaApplicationService.ObterAssociacaoCooperativaPorIdAsync(model.Id);
            model = await AssociacaoCooperativaTransformer.TransformGravarAsync(associacao);
            model.Action = this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
            model.Situacao = EnumSituacaoAssociacaoCooperativa.EmAnalise;
        }
        catch (BusinessException e)
        {
            HandleBusinessException(e);
        }
        //catch(Exception e)
        //{
        //    this.ErrorMessage = e.Message;
        //}

    }

    await this.CarregarGravarViewModelAsync(model);

    return View(model);
}
```

desde já agradeço

Comment: Se o caso é permissão para editar, não seria mais interessante que na "action" da "controller" você verificasse se o usuário possui o privilegio para modificar esse registro?

Comment: ele possui o privilegio para editar, porem só pode editar o registro dele

Comment: Então você pode verificar se o registro é dele e avisar quando não for.

Comment: Sugiro dar uma lida nas diretriz da comunidade, para [criar uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @SylvioT ele pode editar qualquer registro, porem nao pode editar mudando pela URL, se ele quiser deletar ele tem que fazer a busca novamente.

Comment: Você não pode fazer nada para impedir o cliente, o cliente do seu serviço não está sob seu controle. Se o usuário tem permissão de modificar o registro 12 e 13, deixe que ele modifique (se ele alterou "na mão" a url ele sabe que o resultado vai ser diferente do esperado. Se o usuário só tem permissão pro 12 e não pro 13 é obrigação do serviço verificar isso no servidor. O servidor nunca deve confiar nos dados enviados pelo cliente e deve checar tudo no lado do servidor.

Comment: @mari, ele tem permissao, ele pode alterar qualquer registro, só que precisa alterar clicando no mesmo, se passar pela url nao pode alterar. Pq está dando muito problema por incrivel que pareça de usuario dizer clicar em um registro na lista para alterar, ai ele altera na url e acaba mudando outro registro e bagunçando o sitema.

Comment: Não entendi bem. Porque bagunça o sistema? Você pode colocar um log no servidor de qual url foi chamada por qual usuário, daí ele não poderia alegar ter tentado alterar o 12 e chamou passando id 13.

Comment: @StandAlone no seu caso seria mais eficiente você realizar as operações críticas através de métodos POSTs, em métodos GET você sempre passará a informação através da URL

Comment: @StandAlone você pode então verificar na Action de editar se a "url referrer" é diferente de uma url do editar... logo ele não poderá vim direto do editar.

Comment: @Killdary Aguiar de Santana Essas medidas seriam "paliativos": o cliente sempre pode mudar tanto o conteúdo quanto o header do post. Não tem como controlar o que o cliente envia.

Comment: @StandAlone se minha resposta te ajudou, não esqueça de marcá-la como aceita. Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, o usuário tem permissão ao registro, você apenas não quer que ele fique acessando a tela editando parâmetro na URL, com base nisso eu penso nas seguintes soluções.

**Solução 1 - ID Guid**

A primeira solução que imagino é você utilizar um código `Guid` como parâmetro identificador do registro.
Para não ter muitas alterações na estrutura do seu banco de dados, você poderia criar um novo campo na sua tabela que sera do tipo `string`/`varchar` que sera o ID `Guid` do registro, desta forma no parâmetro da `URL` você recebe o ID em `Guid` assim o usuário nunca conseguira acertar um outro `Guid` valido e entrar em outro registro. E você não precisaria alterar o campo ID `long` já existente gerando uma grande alteração no BD.

Sua URL ficaria neste modelo `url/editar/0b2518ca-2100-401f-a810-ecf9a50f4e4d`

Você também precisaria criar algo para gerar o `Guid` pros registros ja existentes e alterar a rota de criação do registro para gerar o `Guid` também.

Para gerar o Guid no C# é só usar o seguinte comando: `Guid.NewGuid();`

**Solução 2 - Solicitar pagina via POST**

A segunda solução que vejo seria na sua listagem dos registros, você chamar uma rota Edit via `POST`e nesta rota setar o ID em uma `ViewBag` ou `TempData`e executar um `RedirectToAction`enviando para rota Edit `GET`, e se nesta rota não tiver dados na ViewBag informado retornar um `BadRequest`.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> RequestEdit(long id)
{
    TempData["IdRegistroSendoAlterado"] = id;

    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id});
}


[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(long id)
{
    if (TempData["IdRegistroSendoAlterado"] == null || 
        id != long.Parse(TempData["IdRegistroSendoAlterado"].ToString()))
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);


    // carregar seu model aqui

    TempData["IdRegistroSendoAlterado"] = id; //Coloca o id denovo na TempData para caso o usuario de F5
    return View();
}
```